# Masking answer options in Confirmit (jscript)

Tags: jscript

I'm trying to mask the answer options that show up in a 3DGrid question item in Confirmit, using the value of a background variable.

E.g. when "background1" ==1, display answer category 1.  If "background1" ==0, do not display answer category 1.  If "background2" ==1, display category 3, otherwise do not.  In any case, display answer category 2.

Hopefully this is easy for someone out there (I'm a psychologist, not a coder...so not so much so for me :/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the data inside a question/variable we can use the f function of confirmit.

for instance:

```
f('my_question_id').get();
```

When masking a question, we need to pass in a Set object so Confirmit knows what `Code`'s to show and not to show.

Often you will mask using a Set from a previous question. So you pass in the question_id and Confirmit does all the other magic.

Here we have the problem of not having a Set, so we will have to create our own.

For this, there are 2 approaches (can be found in the scripting manual under `Working with Sets > Methods of the set Object > add and remove` and `Working with Sets > User defined functions...`)

I'm going to stick to the first one because it is easier to use ;)
What we will do first is create a script node (it doesn't matter where you create it, just somewhere in the survey, I often have a folder Functions with all my script nodes in somewhere at the bottom of my survey)

In that script file we will have our function that crates our set:

```
function CreateMyAwesomeSet()
{
    //create an empty Set
    var mySet = new Set();

    //if background1 equals 1, add 1 to our Set
    if ( f('background1').get() == '1' )
    {
        mySet.add(1);
    }

    //return the Set of allowed Codes
    return mySet;
}
```

Here we declare a function that we now can use wherever we want to.

So now, If we want to use this Set, we add a Code Mask to your grid:

```
CreateMyAwesomeSet()
```

You can ofcourse change the name of the function, and add extra if statements.

hope this helps